# Having tasks complete in background for react native ios

Tags: react-native, react-native-background-fetch

Ive cycled through a number of libraries trying to implement a timer that runs in background for React Native (ios).....after an hour I want user notified that hour has passed (even if app is in background).

Ive tried:

- react-native-background-timer:  flat out doesnt work for ios.....app closes down after less than a minute
- react-native-background-fetch:  app does stay in background.....however there is no control over how often background event fires.  I only want my timer to run for an hour....so if the background event takes a whole day to fire then its useless.

Short question is I want to find a react native library that allows me to run a timer in background from 1 hour to zero....then notifies user that hour has passed (Im using react-native-push-notification for notifications.....and thats working fine).

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you try [react-native-background-actions](https://github.com/Rapsssito/react-native-background-actions)?